# Closure of a certain set

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be the ordered square (i.e. $X= [0,1] \times [0,1]$). X is in the order topology.

Let $A = \bigl\{\frac{1}{n}\times 1: n \in \mathbb{Z}_+\bigr\}$ a subset of X.

Could you please give some idea to find the closure of $A$? Thanks

Comment: I am sure that $\bar A = A \cup \{ (0,1) \}$

Answer (score 0):

The only limit point of $A$ is $0 \times 1$, while all points of $A$ are isolated.

For all $n$, consider the generic open neighbourhood of $\frac{1}{n} \times 1$ (written as an interval)

$$U_{n, \varepsilon, \delta} =\left(\frac{1}{n} \times 1-\varepsilon \ \ , \ \ \frac{1}{n} + \varepsilon \times \delta\right)$$

Every open neighbourhood of $\frac{1}{n} \times 1$ contains an open set of the form $U_{n, \varepsilon, \delta}$.

Comment: Therefore $\bar{A}=A \cup \{(0,1)\}$